# Кастомизация админки Modx

Tags: modx, php

Добрый день, форумчане! У меня вопрос к вам такой: кто занимался реально кастомизацией админки в modx revo. В частности интересует редактирование форм, отвечающих за компонент MiniShop2. В форме заказов добавить новые поля, которые подгружались бы в базу, а также выводились бы в контенте сайта, через плейсхолдеры.

[image]
Например, как тут внести свое новое поле (отредактировав форму, логику административной части сайта).

Спасибо за ответы, если кто даст грамотный ответ.

Comment: Похоже, никто не знает по этой теме. Программисты работающие с фреймворком modx есть тут вообще?)

Comment: Вы один из главных http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/modx/

Comment: @Expert, да я это заметил)))

Comment: нужно еще добавить названия полей в массив в файле /assets/components/minishop2/js/mgr/orders/orders.grid.js на 410 примерно строке. без этого не работало =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение такое по этому вопросу.

1) В настройках системы в поле необходимом добавляем нужные поля. В моем случае это в адресе доставки:

[image]

2) Заходим в управление словарями и создаем константы-заголовки для новых полей в рамках реализации кастомизации админки:

[image]

3) В файле core/components/minishop2/model/minishop2/mysql/msorderadress.map.inc.php вносим изменения в структуру массива в начале файла:

```
array (
     //1
    'user_id' => NULL,
    //2
    'createdon' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    //3
    'updatedon' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    //4
    'receiver' => NULL,
    //5
    'phone' => NULL,
    //6
    'country' => NULL,
    //7
    'index' => NULL,
    //8
    'region' => NULL,
    //9
    'city' => NULL,
    //10
    'metro' => NULL,
    //11
    'street' => NULL,
    //12
    'building' => NULL,
    //13
    'room' => NULL,
    //14
    'comment' => NULL,
    //15
    'name1' => NULL,    
    //16
    'phone1' => NULL,    
    //17
    'datepicker' => NULL,    
    'properties' => NULL,
  ),
```

4) После чего в этом же файле еще создаем свои поля ниже по коду:

```
   /* Свои поля */
    'name1' =>
    array (
      'dbtype' => 'varchar',
      'precision' => '100',
      'phptype' => 'string',
      'null' => true,
    ),

    'phone1' =>
    array (
      'dbtype' => 'varchar',
      'precision' => '50',
      'phptype' => 'string',
      'null' => true,
    ),

    'datepicker' =>
    array (
      'dbtype' => 'varchar',
      'precision' => '255',
      'phptype' => 'string',
      'null' => true,
    ),
   /* конец своих полей */
```

5) Еще открываем сниппет msOrder и дописываем там дополнительные поля для ввода:

```
$user_fields = array(
    'receiver' => 'fullname',
    'phone' => 'phone',
    'email' => 'email',
    'comment' => 'extended[comment]',
    'index' => 'zip',
    'country' => 'country',
    'region' => 'state',
    'city' => 'city',
    'street' => 'address',
    'building' => 'extended[building]',
    'room' => 'extended[room]',
    'name1' => 'name1',
    'phone1' => 'phone1',
    'datepicker' => 'datepicker',
);
```

6) Открываем базу modx и находим таблицу нужную modx_ms2_order_addresses (первый слоган может быть другой, так как это префикс вашей базы). Добавляем туда новые поля, которые прописывали везде.

7) После чего идем в файл core/components/minishop2/model/schema/minishop2.mysql.schema.xml и в структуру файла прописываем те же свои поля, по стандарту документа. И все начинает работать. Теперь админка имеет дополнительные свои поля, количество которых может быть сколько угодно большим.

8) На сайте объявляем нужные плейсхолдеры или добавляем поля с нужными названиями (например: `<input type="text" id="phone1" />`) которое потом при отправке формы добавляет нужные поля в базу и в админку.

9) После ввода данных на сайте о заказе, получаем на выходе дополнительные поля, как показано на картинках:

[image]

[image]

Вот и все готово и работает как надо ;)

Comment: добрый день. сделал всё как описано. в базу значение пишется, но поле в админке не выводится

Comment: user179019, скришоты я же не нарисовал), потому тут либо два варианта, либо Вы где-то ошиблись, либо произошли новые изменения в Modx, в частности в компоненте MiniShop2. Думаю, Вам стоит больше консультироваться с самими разработчиками этого компонента, я же лишь нашел простое решение этой проблемы. До меня программисты там писали просто ужасные огромные коды, которые должны были работать. Почему я и назвал их шаманами, что пляшут возле костра). Сейчас уже не в курсе дел, потому ничего сказать не могу. Веб-программированием уже не занимаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Важный момент: п.3 в префикс_ms2_order_addresses нужно создать колонку с именем вашего плейсхолдера

Comment: вы имеете ввиду в базе данных создать нужные поля? Да я забыл про это рассказать тут.