# Свои поля в заказе minishop2

Tags: php, modx, minishop2

Хочу добавить поле не в раздел адресов, а на первую страницу заказа. прописал указанные в п.п.3-6 изменения соответственно в файлах `msorder.map.inc.php modx_ms2_order`, и данные не вносятся в БД. Хотя если в БД в соответствующем поле вручную внести, то в админке отображается все корректно.

Подскажите, как быть, если не с адресом работать?

Comment: Если всё делать по инструкции - https://bezumkin.ru/modx/minishop2/classes/910/ то всё замечательно работает. Проверено не один раз.

Comment: дело в том что поле нужно в самом заказе а не в товаре или его свойствах, будет предложено на выбор два подарка один из них который выберет клиент будет добавлен к заказу. вот в чем дело, нашел реализацию добавления в заказ своих полей вот по этой ссылке http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-modx произвел соответствующие инструкции действия только в пп. 3-6 в файле msorder.map.inc.php и в таблице БД modx_ms2_order добавил поле akciya